# Requirement already satisfied : .. in /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to install my package using pip from github repository. All actions i do in venv (w/ --no-site-packages). 
In package i use [pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/pbr/). I can't install one of my requirements that located in private repository (i use ssh link), i'm getting strange message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: python>=lpcclient in 
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload (from ansible-lpc-
modules==0.0.1.dev168)
```

*setup.py:*

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(setup_requires=['pbr>=1.8'], pbr=True)
```

*setup.cfg:*

```
[metadata]
name = ansible-lpc-modules
author = Petr
version = 0.0.1
classifier =
    Environment :: OpenStack
    Intended Audience :: Information Technology
    Intended Audience :: System Administrators
    Development Status :: In Progress
    Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
[pbr]
skip_authors = True
skip_changelog = True
[files]
packages =
    ansible/modules/lpc_mdls
    ansible/module_utils/lpc_utils
```

*requirements.txt:*

```
ansible
-e git+ssh://git@git.lpc.org/vpc/python-lpcclient.git@develop#egg=python-lpcclient
```

What i do wrong? I don't have 'lpcclient' installed globally.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--upgrade` handle? e.g. `pip install --upgrade <package_name>`

Comment: @Gannon yup, i've tried but the same thing